# Headless Tinkerboard - Connect to Wifi on boot

Tags: wifi

I have installed `Linux tinkerboard 4.4.103+` on my TinkerBoard.  For security reasons, I have disabled `lightdm`, created a new user and enabled login upon boot.  I have configured the wifi by providing the credentials, by enabling `lightdm` and disabled it again.  Now whenever I boot TinkerBoard, it will boot on command line mode and will request for the login and password.

I have got programs that runs on reboot, for which I have set a cron.  When I boot the tinkerboard, all the programs that should run on boot, runs, without logging into the system.  However, I could connect to the wifi `only if I login and not otherwise.

I do not have much idea about how to set the wifi.  I went through various blogs and web pages related to this and compared it with setting up the wifi for Rpi as well.  I followed the instructions given [here](https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/forum/archive/index.php/thread-902.html) in TinkerBoard forum.  I did the following :

```
sudo apt-get wpasupplicant
wpa_passphrase SSID Password
```

Copied the output to

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ip link show wlan0
```

got the following output

```
wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:03:8c:63:0c:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

sudo /sbin/iw wlan0 scan
```

The above command shows that the tinkerboard is connected to wlan0.

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The above command gave me the following output:

```
Successfully initialised wpa_supplicant
Failed to open config file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf', error: No such file or directory.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'.
```

Since the error was No file, I changed the path fo copy in the above command as follows

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This gave me the following output:

```
Successfully initialised spa_supplicant
ioctl(SIOCSIWAP): Operation not permitted
ioctl(SIOCSIWENDODEEXT): Invalid argument
ioctl(SIOCSIWENCODEEXT): Invalid argument
```

I ran all the codes as root only.  The problem that I am facing is, the tinkerboard is not connecting to internet on boot, but does so only when I login using loginid and password.

Since the tinker boards are installed at client's location the requirement for login id and password becomes mandatory.  Besides the programs should run on powering on the device.    And to reiterate, my other bash scripts are running with no trouble even without logging into the system.  However, the tinkerboard connects to internet only when I login into the system.  How do I connect to wifi upon booting the tinkerboard.

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions given online worked.  I have retained the NetworkManager.service.  Logged in, into the system and selected the wifi from the `Start` --> `preferences` --> `Network Connections`.  Changed the setting to include all the users of `tinkerboard` which resolved the issue.

Comment: I spent some time to find a solution, and to be honest did not expect this. My issue was exactly the same, all jobs were running without any issue but I could not ssh in without first logging on directly with keyboard and screen. I however noticed that wlan was writing stuff on cli logon screen until I logged on. You should accept your answer.